# Python, how to read in flat file and populating information into relevant column by recognizing delimiter for each column in the file

Tags: python, mysql

I have a large text file in the form of:

```
    #index1
    #* Title of paper
    #@ Author of paper
    #t Year
```

with thousands of papers in that form. In python, I am trying to read the file line by line and when it comes to for example #*, I want to populate what comes after that into the TITLE column of a table I have already created. I would just like to understand how to write code in python that will recognize the unique symbols for each column and insert the information into the relevant column in the table. I am new to python and databases so I apologize if this is not a clear enough question!!

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary which you can use to map the column names with the symbol. If its a text file you can open the file with following code:

```
symbolsDirectory = {"#*":"Title of Paper", "#@": "Author of paper", "#t": "year"}
fileContent = open(file).readlines()
```

file content now has all the lines in a list. Now you can use a loop to go through the list. In the loop you want to parse the string to get the symbol. Use that symbol to get the column name from the dictionary. Afterwards in the loop you can even add the logic to add the string in database if that is what you are trying to do.

You can parse the string to get the symbols with following code:

```
for line in fileContent:
    symbol = line[0:2]
```

I hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: Matching symbols like this is much easier than my method, +1. Note however that if you have symbols of varying length, `line[0:2]` will not cover you. Currently, to match your `#index1` line, you would have to rely on logic similar to "symbol matched nothing else, it's probably an index".

Comment: I see what you are saying. Since the question is only showing the case where he is only using symbols that are 2 char long. Here is something you can add before the `symbol = line[0:2] ` 

You can add `i = line.find(" ")` which will give you the index of first occurrence of space. You can then change the 2 to i in the line like this: `symbol = line[0:i]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` module to get all values, than use `zip` to get list of tuples.

```
# +\n is used to select the last item in the file content
s=open('file.txt', 'r').read()+'\n'

import re

titles = re.findall('(?<=#\*).*(?=\n)', s)
authors = re.findall('(?<=#@).*(?=\n)', s)
years = re.findall('(?<=#t).*(?=\n)', s)

values = zip(titles, authors, years)
```

Answer (score 0):

To read line by line, you can use the file as an iterator:

```
records = []

with open(my_file) as file:
     # do stuff
     pass
```

I suggest you define four functions that can each parse a type of line:

```
def parse_index(line):
    pass

def parse_title(line):
    pass

def parse_author(line):
    pass

def parse_year(line):
    pass
```

Using regular expressions (hopefully you are already familiar with the syntax), it is possible to "pattern match" those lines, in order to extract data. Here is an example:

```
import re
def parse_author(line):
    PATTERN = re.compile(r'#@ (.*)')
    match = PATTERN.match(line)

    if match:
        # if we have a match, what we need is stored in the first
        # capture group; more on this later
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        # raise TypeError('Line does not match expected format')
        return None
```

The regular expression I used above consists of this:

`#@ (.+)`:

- Match a literal octothorpe (`#`)
- Match a literal at sign (`@`)
- Match a space
- Starting from the opening parenthesis, capture the sub-pattern in a group
- Match any character (`.`) – at least once (`+`)
- End the capture group (`)`)

The final code might look something like this:

```
records = []

with open(my_file) as file:
    # seek to end of file to find out how long it is
    eof = file.seek(0,2)
    file.seek(0) # back to start

    # the check tests whether we reached the end of the file
    while file.tell() < eof:
        record = {}
        record['index'] = parse_index(file.readline())
        record['title'] = parse_title(file.readline())
        record['author'] = parse_author(file.readline())
        record['year'] = parse_year(file.readline())

        # do something with record, e.g. append it to a list
        records.append(record)

# do something with all records, e.g.:
for record in records:
    print(record)
```

There are many ways to skin a cat, and you'll find out by writing your own code that you will discover more elegant ways of doing it.

Comment: I went the regex way, even if it is not strictly necessary here, because regex are mighty useful (better learn them now than later) and if the format ever changes slightly, a regex can be easily changed, as opposed to logic in code.